# Java: Return char Instead of double in Method

Tags: java, methods, char, return, double

I have a simple program that uses methods to find the largest of, and the product of variables `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Just to explore, is there a way to write code into the methods to return "A", "B", etc. instead of just the value?

```
public class methods
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int A=1, B=10, C=-5, D=20;
        System.out.println("The largest of A and B is " + Largest(A,B));
        System.out.println("The largest of A, B and C is " + Largest(A,B,C));
        System.out.println("The largest of A, B, C and D is " + Largest(A,B,C,D));
        System.out.println("The product of A and B is " + Product(A,B));
        System.out.println("The product of A, B and C is " + Product(A,B,C));
        System.out.println("The product of A, B, C and D is " + Product(A,B,C,D));
    }

    public static double Largest(int A, int B)
    {
        if (A > B)
        return A;
        else
        return B;
    }

    public static double Largest(int A, int B, int C)
    {
        if (A > B && A > C)
        return A;
        else if (B > A && B > C)
        return B;
        else
        return C;
    }

    public static double Largest(int A, int B, int C, int D)
    {
        if (A > B && A>C && A>D)
        return A;
        else if (B > A && B>C && B>D)
        return B;
        else if (C > B && C>A && C>D)
        return C;
        else
        return D;
    }

    public static double Product(int A, int B)
    {
        return A*B;
    }

    public static double Product(int A, int B, int C)
    {
        return A*B*C;
    }

    public static double Product (int A, int B, int C, int D)
    {
        return A*B*C*D;
    }

}
```

Comment: your methods return a `double`, because you put `double` as return type. If you want to return a `char`, change your return type to `char`, and return a `char` literal instead of the number inputs (e.g. `if(A>B) return 'A';`)

Comment: Wow. So, simple and I skipped right over it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a char return type instead of double for your methods. Also you have a few formatting issues that you should fix. Your method identifier Largest() should be largest(), with a lowercase "l". Capital letters are reserved for class names and constructors. Also your variables A,B,C,D should also be lowercase. Variables that are all caps should only be used for final variables. For example,

```
final int MAX = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

better to use this logic to find out largest among three

```
 public static double Largest(int A, int B, int C) // complexity of program is getting reduced just by minimizing the comparison.
    {
        if (A > B){   //a is greater than B
           if(A>C)         
            return A;  //return a if A is largest among three
           else
              return B  // return B if B is largest among three
         }else{        
           if(B>C)      //this statement will execute if B>A.
              return B;  //return B if B is largest amoung three.
           else
              return C;  // return C if C is largest among three.
         }     
    }
```

Comment: It returns 1 when`A=3`, `B=1`, `C=5`.